# io.vertx.oracleclient.OracleException: Error : 1000, Position : 0, Sql = SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

Tags: oracle, kotlin, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I have one question regarding oracle cursors . Actually I upgraded my project to latest vert.x version and now I started to see some errors. I have one SQL Verticle which actively used and it throw exception after a while. You can see on below :

```
 "io.vertx.oracleclient.OracleException: Error : 1000, Position : 0, Sql = SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED, OriginalSql = SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED, Error Msg = ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded"
```

I am using withTransaction method belong to vertx-sql-client:4.2.7 and  I am not sure whether I manage it myself or vertx manage. I expected that cursors already managed by vertx. Is there anybody who see such an error ? or Any comment ? Thanks in advance .

Also Any idea why vertx open cursor for sql "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED, OriginalSql = SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" and not close ?

Example code :

```
   override suspend fun processItem(callback: Callback) {
pool.withTransaction { conn ->
     conn.query("select *  from TABLE where ROWNUM='1'") .execute()
}}
```

Comment: Can you [file an issue](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) with details about how to reproduce please? Thank you

Comment: Hi @tsegismont, I created an issue so you can check it from there : 
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/1187